# Работа с Parcelable объектом в обратном направлении

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте, уважаемые Хешкодовцы!

Вот есть такая интересная задачка. Есть Parcelable обьект, который гуляет по активностям. Возьмем следующую ситуацию.  Есть две активности:

1. Запустили активность (A), создали Parcelable объект
2. Из активности A запустим активность B и передадим в активность B  Parcelable обьект
3. **Важно, при запуски активности B *не завершим активность A***
4. Сохраним что то в обьект Parcelable в активности B.
5. И.......... Нажимаем мнопку Back или просто finish() делаем
6. Из заднего плана разворачивается активность A, но вот про наш Parcelable объект из B она не в курсе.

Вот тут самое интересное, так как активность A не была завершена, мы не можем ее стартовать и передать новый Parcelable объект.

*Отсюда и такой интересный вопрос: работа с Parcelable объектами в обратном направлении.*

Заранее, спасибо!!!

Comment: так есть же рестарт

Comment: А можно пример кода пожалуйста, либо туплю нереально... Либо не понимаю что то :(

Answer (score 3):

`Activity` B запускаем через `startActivityForResult()` и возвращаем результат через `setResult()`, в `Activity` A — получаем этот результат в `onActivityResult()`.